# Cypress: Can't use --env variables from command line in test file

Tags: javascript, configuration, cypress

In my Cypress setup I have the following values (plus others) in my cypress.json file:

```
{
 "PREPROD": {
    "url": "https://preprod.com",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
  },
 "PROD": {
    "url": "https://prod.com",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
  }
}
```

I have my test file located in cypress/integration/test.js

Based on what environment I want to run my test, I'd like to use the values relevant to that environment in my test file

I've tried running like this:

```
npx cypress run --env environment="PREPROD" --spec "cypress/integration/test.js"
```

This returns an error saying that environment is not defined.

In my test file I have the following to use the variable from command line:

```
Cypress.config().environment.username
```

How do I go about using the variables that I define in command line?
I've tried reading the documentation here but its not working for me: [Cypress Documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Setting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can access the `environment` variable like this:

```
Cypress.env('environment')
```

If you want to get the options depending on this you could do as follow:

```
const CypressConfiguration = require('cypress.json')

const environment = Cypress.env('environment') || 'PREPROD'

const options = CypressConfiguration[environment]
```

One other approach would be to use the `config-file` option:

**cypress.prod.json**

```
{
    "url": "https://prod.com",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
}
```

**cypress.preprod.json**

```
{
    "url": "https://preprod.com",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
}
```

Then:

```
npx cypress run --config-file cypress.prod.json --spec "cypress/integration/test.js"
```

Comment: My problem is that Cypress.env('environment') does not pull the value from command line either.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add another approach. By the way, is the command you're running different from the one you've posted in the question?

Comment: I've taken your approach of using the config files, its nice. To get my test working, I have to have one slight difference to what you've defined. I need to call my variables from the config file like this: Cypress.config.environment
I still don't understand why .env doesn't work though.

Comment: Reproducing your problem is a bit cumbersome. I can't help you with that if you don't create a sandbox or a GitHub repository. If the other approach is fine for you, please upvote and validate my answer :)